# Need to get the attribute value from the another XML file element

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to replace the attribute from the another xml file:

Input html file:

```
<p class="p heading">Heading</p>
<p class="normal">Text</p>
```

I'm having the above input file which consist class attribute, I want to replace the new value for the class attribute while XSLT convert

class.xml(seperate file):

```
   <name>
      <old>heading</old>
      <new>Headings</new>
   </name>
   <name>
      <old>normal</old>
      <new>Actual</new>
   </name>
```

XSL I'm having:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected Output:

```
<p class="Headings">Heading</p>
<p class="Actual">Text</p>
```

Need to replace the old attribute value with new.

Comment: I could understand the mapping from `normal` to `Actual` but why should `p heading` be mapped to `Headings`? Is the `p` meant to be removed if there is no mapping?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, the input HTML is having multiple attributes in single class, So I want to neglect `p` and take only `heading` for that types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a key and simply match the attributes `class` having a reference and transform them

```
  <xsl:param name="class-map">
   <name>
      <old>heading</old>
      <new>Headings</new>
   </name>
   <name>
      <old>normal</old>
      <new>Actual</new>
   </name>
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:key name="class-map" match="name/new" use="../old"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="p/@class[key('class-map', tokenize(.), $class-map)]">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="key('class-map', tokenize(.) , $class-map)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Handle the rest by the identity transformation. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9P has an XSLT 3 online sample. Of course the document `class-map` could be loaded with `doc` or `document` (e.g. `<xsl:param name="class-map" select="doc('class.xml')"/>`) from a file or a URI in general, only inline above for completeness and compactness of the example.

Comment: Please see the related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245283/need-to-include-the-element-inside-the-attribute-template