# Need to remove the extra normal element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I'm having the element which coming repeatedly, need to remove the element and rearrange it

Input XML:

```
<section>
<p class="p heading">Heading</p>
<p class="normal">Text</p>
<ul>
<li><p class="p"><span class="bold">Check</span> - Remaining</p></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

XSL I'm having, In that I'm changing list para and into normal para:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="class-map">
   <name>
      <old>heading</old>
      <new>Headings</new>
   </name>
   <name>
      <old>normal</old>
      <new>Actual</new>
   </name>
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:key name="class-map" match="name/new" use="../old"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="p/@class[key('class-map', tokenize(.), $class-map)]">
      <xsl:attribute name="style">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="key('class-map', tokenize(.) , $class-map)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <normal>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </normal>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[@class='bold']">
    <normal style="CD Bold">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </normal>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ul">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="li">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
<section>
   <p style="Headings"><normal>Heading</normal></p>
   <p style="Actual"><normal>Text</normal></p>
   <p class="p"><normal style="CD Bold">Check</normal><normal style="normal"> - Remaining</normal></p>
</section>
```

Need to remove the extra `normal` element and make it bold for Bold class and rearrange it on another place of normal text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it simply I wrote the same XML incoming file as you had so it's the same in- and output.

Here is the XML/HTML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>
    <p class="p heading">Heading</p>
    <p class="normal">Text</p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p class="p">
                <span class="bold">Check</span> - Remaining
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Notes:
For HTML tags we don't need to use:

```
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
```

You should be careful when importing some libraries. If you've added too many, your code will take more time. This is because your code must first create all references to the links and .co. That can be cause some errors too just like in Java.

With `[@...='...']` we can call specific modifications of an element like `<normal style="CD Bold">` for example:
`normal[@style='CD Bold'`

My resault:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xe.source ../TemporaryFiles/Test_XML_1.xml?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output media-type="text/xml" method="xml"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <section>
            <p style="Headings">
                <normal>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/section/p[@class='p heading']"></xsl:value-of>
                </normal>
            </p>
            <p style="Actual">
                <normal>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/section/p[@class='normal']"></xsl:value-of>
                </normal>
            </p>
            <p class="p">
                <normal style="CD Bold">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/section/ul/li/p[@class='p']/span[@class='bold']"></xsl:value-of>
                </normal>
                <normal style="normal">
                    -<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(/section/ul/li/p[@class='p'],'-')"></xsl:value-of>
                 </normal>
            </p>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `<?xe.source ../Temporary Files/Test_XML_1.xml?>` line is used for adding the XML file directly to the XSLT File. The path should be another on yours

I achived with that simple XSLT file your expection.

Here is the resault:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>
    <p style="Headings">
        <normal>Heading</normal>
    </p>
    <p style="Actual">
        <normal>Text</normal>
    </p>
    <p class="p">
        <normal style="CD Bold">Check</normal>
        <normal style="normal"> - Remaining </normal>
    </p>
</section>
```

if you want to get bouth bold in `<p class="p">` you can use thise lines of code here:

```
                 <normal style="CD Bold">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/section/ul/li/p[@class='p']/span[@class='bold']"></xsl:value-of> - <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(/section/ul/li/p[@class='p'],' - ')"></xsl:value-of>
                 </normal>
```

Comment: While the namespace declarations you have listed are not needed for the simple example they certainly don't import any libraries, they are just namespace declarations (probably taken from a boilerplate to have commonly used namespaces in XSLT 3 predeclared.).

Comment: Ok, nice to know :) I didn't know that. Always thought it would be an implementation xD thanks. But even then it could cause some mistakes. In my own project that I'm working on, this has caused quite a few problems ^^